# TemplateDoesNotExist at / in Django/Python Application

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to run a Django Application with PyCharm and getting this error:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.14
Installed Applications:
('django_admin_bootstrapped',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'compressor',
'menu',
'django_extensions',
'estabelecimento',
'bootstrap3',
'django_autocomplete',
'easy_select2',
'daterange_filter',
'qrcode')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Users\Marcos\PycharmProjects\japedi\django_admin_bootstrapped\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\compressor\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Marcos\PycharmProjects\japedi\bootstrap3\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Marcos\PycharmProjects\japedi\daterange_filter\templates\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Marcos\PycharmProjects\japedi\qrcode\templates\index.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
137.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
78.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in resolve_template
54.             return loader.select_template(template)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in select_template
194.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(not_found))

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: index.html
```

There are some directorys called templates inside the project. For every specific application there is one folder templates inside them. Anybody could help me with this? There is a version in a production environment with linux in digital ocean working good. I am trying to run locally in my machine with windows 10.

I tried put DIRS in settings.py, but with no comma and with "=" instead of ":", with no success. And my INSTALLED_APPS section is like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'compressor',
    'menu',
    'django_extensions',
    'estabelecimento',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_autocomplete',
    'easy_select2',
    'daterange_filter',
    'qrcode'
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'grappelli2/templates'),
)
```

Do I need to have and index.html file in the root folder? Because I only have a index.wsgi.

[Project Structure and views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtKVO.jpg)

Comment: The file `index.html`, can you show the views.py code that you are using to load it? And the folder structure for your project

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with a print of my views.py and my project structure print.

Comment: Please include your template settings (in Django 1.7 they all start `TEMPLATE_`, e.g. `TEMPLATE_DIRS`). Note that Django 1.7 is end of life and no longer receives security updates. Where is the `index.html` template actually located in your project?

Comment: Actually, I don´t have any index.html file in my root folder, only inside every "template folder", inside "grapelli2" folder. See the url in production environment: 

http://192.241.241.25/japedi/admin/login/?next/japedi/admin/

Answer (score 0):

A few things can cause this.

1. If the html file you're trying to load is in a templates folder in the root of your project, then you need to make sure it can be found.

Go to your settings.py, TEMPLATES section, and set the 'DIRS' as follows.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

2. If the file you want is in a templates directory within an app, then
   make sure that app is in the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings.py

This final idea is a long shot, and shouldn't be a problem, but if both of the above are correct, try this.

I notice a while back I could get this error in PyCharm if there was no comma after the last app in the INSTALLED_APPS list.

Weirdly, if I added the comma and got the app running, I could then remove the comma, and it would still work.

I don't think this still happens, but work a look if all else fails.

-Richard

Comment: Note that this answer is for the `TEMPLATES` setting in Django 1.8+. The OP is using Django 1.7.1.